# Calling several python programs consecutively, but with different global variables

Tags: python, variables, call

I have different python programs, which all have 2 set global variables (set outside of any function or the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

I want to call this python programs consecutively, but with changing their global variables all to set values.

Like pseudocode:

```
with variables ... (overwriting the global variables of the afterward called programs.

python_program 1 
python_program 2
python_program 3
```

Does someone how I can do that? I can't call the main function with variables, because then I get an error because the variables get evaluated before being defined.

I was thinking about creating a file that all programs can import and use as global variables. The above in pseudocode shown script could then maybe just edit that file?

Comment: Global variables are error-prone. You may try to create another file as you told but without knowing what those variables are for, it is not easy to guide you. You may also consider environment variables to set for each script.

Comment: The global variables are for a subprocess which get called in a function of the python program.
Do you know how I would set and import such a file in the programs aswell as in the script?

Comment: You can create a file as module, import it in your programs and put functions in them. functions returns list of arguments required for subprocess and use it like `subprocess.run([*mymodule.args()])`

Comment: Ok and what would I have to put in mymodule.py?

Comment: def args(): return ["arg1", "arg2"]